# WSDL - soap:operation/@soapAction - needs to be unique?

Tags: soap, wsdl

In WSDL1.1, does each `binding/operation/soap:operation/@soapAction` have to be unique inside it's containing binding?  If not, how does the SOAP/WSDL server know which "matching" operation to invoke?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure the SOAP Action has to be unique, it's the part of the request (for HTTP transports, it's in the form of an HTTP header) which uniquely identifies the operation. Essentially, the SOAP Action is the URI *of* the operation.

Having said that, in many cases the SOAP action header is redundant, since the type of the SOAP payload is often enough to uniquely identify the target operation.

Comment: The spec says this:

"...For other SOAP protocol bindings, it MUST NOT be specified, and the soap:operation element MAY be omitted."

No word on uniqueness :-(  Looking up the target operation based on the input XML seems prone to error, what if 2 different operations have the same input XML?

I agree with you that the it makes sense for the SOAPAction to be unique, I'm surprised that the spec hasn't explicitly stated this.  All I can guess is that this is an "implementation detail" that the spec authors purposefully omitted.  Unless I'm missing something this seems a strange decision.